# SQL query to get child count and sum it

Tags: sql, oracle

My table is kind of like :

```
    ID    CODE    SUB_CODE
  ------ ------ ------------
  |  1  |  A   |    A1     |
  --------------------------
  |  2  |  A   |    A1     |
  --------------------------
  |  3  |  A   |    A3     |
  --------------------------
  |  4  |  B   |    B1     |
```

the result I am trying to get is :

```
CODE   CODE_COUNT   SUB_CODE   SUB_CODE_COUNT
 A         3           A1            2
 A         3           A3            1
 B         1           B1            1
```

So the `SUB_CODE_COUNT` is the sum count of each unique `SUB_CODE`, and `CODE_COUNT` is the sum count of all `SUB_CODE` for that `CODE`

This what I have right now:

```
SELECT
   CODE,
   SUB_CODE,
   COUNT(SUB_CODE) AS SUB_CODE_COUNT,
FROM
   TABLENAME
GROUP BY
   CODE, SUB_CODE
```

Result:

```
CODE   SUB_CODE   SUB_CODE_COUNT
 A        A1            2
 A        A3            1
 B        B1            1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analytic functions:

```
SELECT CODE, SUB_CODE,
       COUNT(*) AS SUB_CODE_COUNT,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE) as CODE_COUNT
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY CODE, SUB_CODE;
```